# Error: Upstream proxy port is required while creating spfx project

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I am facing some issues while creating an **SPFX** project from cmd.

Below is the error screenshot.

[image]

Does anyone have solution to this error?

Comment: Definitely a proxy issue, try to do outside of your network for example via 4G or mobile network.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if you have created spfx solution correctly according to the articles below.

[Steps To Create Basic SPFx Solution And Deploy On SharePoint Online.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-for-create-basic-spfx-solution-and-deploy-in-sharepoint-online/)

[Build your first SharePoint client-side web part (Hello World part 1).](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

[Build And Deploy The Client Side Web Part (SPFx) In SharePoint Online.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/build-and-deploy-the-client-side-web-part-spfx-in-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: I have checked everything, I work under a proxy so I face these kind of errors..for this one, I am not able to find solution yet